# List splitting for RLE compression algorithm

Tags: python

I try to implement a simple RLE compression algorithm as a learning task. In the first step, i need to split my source list to sequences of repeating and non-repeating elements. I've done it, but code seems to be so ugly. Can I simplify it?

```
src = [1,1,2,3,3,4,2,1,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,4,5]

from itertools import izip

isRepeat = False
sequence = []

def out(sequence):
    if sequence:
        print sequence

def testRepeate(a, b, pr):
    global isRepeat
    global sequence
    if a == b:
        if isRepeat:
            sequence.append(pr)
        else:
            out(sequence)
            sequence = []
            sequence.append(pr)
            isRepeat = True
    else:
        if isRepeat:
            sequence.append(pr)
            out(sequence)
            sequence = []
            isRepeat = False
        else:
            sequence.append(pr)


for a, b in izip(src[:-1], src[1:]):
    testRepeate(a, b, a)
testRepeate(src[-2], src[-1], src[-1])
out(sequence)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I must tell you that Python makes astonishing easy to write a [Run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding):

```
>>> src = [1,1,2,3,3,4,2,1,3,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,4,5]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>>
>>> [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k,g in groupby(src)]
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (3, 5), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
```

Take a look at how [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to see how a generator will be a good choice for this kind of task

---

But that doesn't mean that it wasn't a bad idea try to implement it yourself. So let's take a deeper look at your code :)

**The best use of `global` is usually the one that doesn't use `global` at all**

The use of the `global` keyword among beginners is almost always a sign of trying to program using some other language's mindset. Usually, if a function need to know the value of somthing, pass that something along as an argument.

In your case, what you need, is a function that loops through your list holding the value of `isRepeat`.

Something like this:

```
def parse(seq):
    is_repeat = False
    old = None
    for num in seq:
        is_repeat = num == old    # will be True or False
        if is_repeat:
            # ...
```

I didn't go too far since, as you may have already noticed, the `is_repeat` flag is a bit useless now, so we'll get rid of that later.

You may have also noted that I called `isReapeat` `is_repeat`, I did that to follow some naming style guide (see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more info).

**Cleared this, let's get at your statement:**

> In the first step, I need to split my source list to sequences of repeating and non-repeating elements.

Ok, to split a sequence we'll have to parse it item by item, so while we'll be at it why don't already count how many times an item occurs?

The wrong step was to build a `testRepeat` function, such function should act on 2 items at the time, but that will lose the "view" of the whole sequence one item after the other. Well ok, a recursive solution could also be found, but I can't go through all the possible solutions.

So, to do achive our goal one could:

- parse the list item by item.
- see if an item is the same as the previous one.
- if it is `count += 1`.
- else store that item with its count.

This might be the code:

```
def rle(seq):
    result = []
    old = seq[0]
    count = 1
    for num in seq[1:]:
        if num == old:
            count += 1
        else:
            result.append((old, count))   # appending a tuple
            count = 1      # resetting the counting
            old = num
    result.append((old, count))    # appending the last counting
    return result
```

There could still be room for improvement (also it doesn't handle empty list like *hdima* noticed), but I just wanted to show an easy example and premature optimization is the root of (most) evil. (Also, there's groupby waiting to be used.)

**Notes**

It's very common to fall in some of the mistakes you did. Keep trying and you'll get better. Keep also in mind some of the following:

- Think hard about the your design.
- Do you really need an `out` function? Couldn't you just place the code there?
- Do you really want to not print at all, if you get an empty list? I would really like to see what my code is returning, so I wouldn't block its output.
- Don't write cryptic code, write readable one.
  What are `a`, `b` and `pr`. A variable name should be something that reflect what it holds.
- The same could be said for `sequence`, if `sequece` is the resulting sequence call it `result` or something like that.
- Whorship [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) as an almighty guide!

Comment: The `rle()` function needs to be fixed. Currently it's always lose the last element and raise `IndexError` for empty `seq`.

Comment: @Nativeborn: Yes `groupby` is the right tool. Knowing the standard library is a must, but I hope you got that the main point was to learn something and improve one's own coding skills :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your solution is overly over-engineered. To implement [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) algorithm you just need to iterate over the input sequence and store the current element and the counter. For example the following code implements RLE for lists:

```
def rle(src):
    result = []
    if src:
        current = src.pop(0)
        counter = 1
        for e in src:
            if e == current:
                counter += 1
            else:
                result.append((counter, current))
                current = e
                counter = 1
        result.append((counter, current))
    return result
```

And the following code for any iterator:

```
def irle(src):
    iterator = iter(src)
    current = next(iterator)
    counter = 1
    for e in iterator:
        if e == current:
            counter += 1
        else:
            yield counter, current
            current = e
            counter = 1
    yield counter, current
```

Some usage examples:

```
>>> rle([])
[]
>>> rle([1])
[(1, 1)]
>>> rle([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
[(3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
>>> list(irle(iter([])))
[]
>>> list(irle(iter([1])))
[(1, 1)]
>>> list(irle(iter([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3])))
[(3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for correction. But I think, that `itertools` will be more convinient.

Comment: However `itertools.groupby` is more convenient in Python, but if you know _how_ to implement the algorithm then you can implement it in any language.